# How to draw a coordinate map containing both horizontal and vertical boxplot with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to draw a picture like this using matplotlib.

How to do that?

Thank you in advance.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk57A.png)/i.stack.imgur.com/Vk57A.png

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

[`seaborn.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) might be what you're looking for. Specify to draw boxplots in the marginal plot and a regplot in the "main plot".

Seaborn builds on top of matplotlib, so you can still modify linecolors, markercolors etc. and draw annotations with `plt.annotate`.